# Property value assignment

Tags: c#, properties

I am not understanding why the *first* block of the code is *valid* but not the *latter*:

```
var e = new Exception()
{
    Data =
    {
        {"a","a"}
    }
};
```

Compile-time error here:

```
e.Data =
{
    {"a","a"}
};
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the complete error message you get.

Comment: Maybe if you move the cursor above the text that has the red underline it will give you the answer. Or Ctrl click into `Data` to see the member definition.

Comment: `Data` property has been declared as `public virtual IDictionary Data { get; }` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.exception.data?view=net-6.0); you can just *initialize* readonly property

Comment: Please do not format code as pictures, instead put it as markdown text in your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The other answer isn't 100% accurate. Yes, `Data` is a readonly property. However, a readonly (i.e., getter-only) property can *only* be given an initial/default value (in which case, the value is assigned to the compiler-generated backing field), but it *cannot* be assigned to; period. Not in the object initializer, not in the constructor, and not anywhere else.

<sup>Note that readonly *fields*, on the other hand, can be assigned to in the constructor.</sup>

In order to assign to a property, it *must* have a setter (e.g., `set;`, `private set;`, etc.) and if you're using C# 9.0 or above, you could use an [init-only setter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-9.0/init) (i.e., `init;`) which will allow you to assign to the property in the object initializer but not after that.

As long as the property doesn't have a setter, you can never *directly* change its value. To prove this, try setting `Data` to `null` in the object initializer:

```
var e = new Exception()
{
    Data = null  // Nope, compiler won't allow it because Data is readonly
};
```

**So, why does it work in the first block?**

That's because you're initializing `Data` using a [Collection Initializer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers#collection-initializers). When you do that, the compiler doesn't actually assign a value to the property. Instead, it calls the `Add()` method. You can see this for yourself [here](https://sharplab.io/#v2:CYLg1APgAgTAjAWAFBQMwAJboMLoN7LpGYZQAs6AsgBQCU+hxTAbgIYBO6ApugLzoA7LgHd0AUQAeAYy4AHAC4BLAPYDGTIgSQad6ACKt5rPut2bTZpngBErawBpb19AF8Lut9o8BuU55dAA). The first (i.e., working) block is translated by the compiler to:

```
Exception e = new Exception();
e.Data.Add("a", "a"); // <-- Ah! `Data` was never assigned to.
```

..which, by the way, would *normally* throw a NullReferenceException (because we're calling the `Add()` method on a property that should be null). But if you look at the [source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/exception.cs,33f0ea57f71b3a1e) of `Exception.Data`, you see that its backing field is always initialized in the getter so that it's never null:

> ```
> public virtual IDictionary Data { 
>     [System.Security.SecuritySafeCritical]  // auto-generated
>     get {
>         if (_data == null)
>             if (IsImmutableAgileException(this))
>                 _data = new EmptyReadOnlyDictionaryInternal();
>             else
>                 _data = new ListDictionaryInternal();
>         
>         return _data;
>     }
> }
> ```

Answer (score 3):

Well `Data` property has been [declared](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.exception.data?view=net-6.0) as *readonly* property:

```
public virtual System.Collections.IDictionary Data { get; }
```

That's why you can **initialize** it (i.e. set in constructor)

```
  // Create an instance, initialize `Data` with { "a", "a" }
  Exception e = new Exception() {
    Data = { { "a", "a" } }
  };
```

But you can't **set** it:

```
 // Trying to set Data as { { "a", "a" } };
 e.Data = { { "a", "a" } }; // <- Compile time error here
```

> Error CS0200  Property or indexer 'Exception.Data' cannot be assigned to -- it is **read only** (**bold** is mine, Dmitry Bychenko)

Please note, that you can just **add** required items into `Data`:

```
  Exception e = new Exception();

  // Add {"a", "a"} to existing Data
  e.Data.Add("a", "a");
```

Comment: This isn't entirely accurate. _"That's why you can initialize it (i.e. set in constructor)"_ Actually, you can't. It only works in this specific case because the collection initializer is being used. Please refer to my answer for more details.

Answer (score 0):

you can not assignt data because Data is a dictionary. You could assignt the new dictionary object if it had a setter, but Data has only a getter and it is created as an empty collection on init

```
public class ABC
{
 public virtual System.Collections.IDictionary Data { get; } =  new Dictionary<object,object> ();
}
```

you can only init it by some data the same way as any another collection using a Collection Initializer

```
    var abc = new ABC()
    {
        Data = {
        {"a","a"}
       }
    };
```

or add new item by two common ways, the same as you are using any another dictionary

```
    abc.Data["c"] = "c";
    //or 
    abc.Data.Add("d", "d");
}
```